# How to get a list of installed programmes with python?

Tags: python, gtk

I'd like to make a programme, which would allow a user to choose, which application to run. I understand, it is possible to just run a command, which user specifies, but it would be much nicer, if it was possible to also give the user a list of all programmes, of which he or she could choose. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: If you downvote the question, please, tell, what is wrong, so I could improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `GtkAppChooser` is probably what you want. Here is an example:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

dialog = Gtk.AppChooserDialog()
dialog.set_heading("Choose an application below")
widget = dialog.get_widget()
widget.set_show_all(True)
response = dialog.run()
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    appinfo = dialog.get_app_info()
    print "Selected:", appinfo.get_name()
    appinfo.launch(None, None)
```

Have a look at [this documentation page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/ApplicationChoosing.html) which will show the `GtkAppChooserWidget`, `GtkAppChooseButton` and `GtkAppChooseDialog` to implement inside your application, and the `GtkAppChooser` interface to work with the options.

`GAppInfo.launch()` [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.34/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-launch).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks, like what I need! It is a pity, I can't find a documentation for PyGObject, but I hope your example will be sufficient for me.
Also, would you happen to know, how to run the application, I get from that dialog, using python? Or is there a way to get a command, which you can just run, to launch the chosen application?

Comment: Just use the C docs. They are very good and translation to Python is very straightforward. `GtkAppChooser.get_app_info()` returns a `GAppInfo` which has a `launch()` method. (https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.34/GAppInfo.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I hope, that will do it.